# Execute a `List` of `IO` in parallel

Tags: scala, scala-cats

This is an example when we want to execute 3 `IO` in parallel

```
def test: Unit = {
    val ioA = IO.shift *> IO(println("Running ioA"))
    // ioA: cats.effect.IO[Unit] = <function1>

    val ioB = IO.shift *> IO(println("Running ioB"))
    // ioB: cats.effect.IO[Unit] = <function1>

    val ioC = IO.shift *> IO(println("Running ioC"))
    // ioC: cats.effect.IO[Unit] = <function1>

    val program: IO[Unit] = (ioA, ioB, ioC).parMapN { (_, _, _) => () }
    // program: cats.effect.IO[Unit] = <function1>

    program.unsafeRunSync()
  }
```

First question: What if the point of using `IO.shift` in this example ?

Second question: What if we have a `List` of `IO` we want to execute in parallel ? I've created a function for this task but I don't know if this thing existed already in the library

```
def parallelize(ios: List[IO[Unit]]): IO[Unit] = {
    ios.foldLeft(IO.pure(())) { case (currentResult, currentItem) =>
      (currentResult, currentItem).parMapN((_, _) => ())
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works with "cats-core:1.1.0" and "cats-effect:0.10.1"

```
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.parallel._

//ios: List[IO[A]]
ios.parSequence //IO[List[A]]
```

Comment: How to execute Map[A, IO[B]] in parallel?

Comment: @KumarWaghmode convert it to a list and then you will have `List[(A, IO[B])]`. Then you can use `IO.pure` along with `flatMap` to make `List[IO[(A, B)]]`. After that use `parSequence` and convert back to `Map` if needed.